# Bootstrap - Carousel | Links not working

Tags: carousel

I have been using a video tutorial for Bootstrap Carousel and somehow my code is same as per the video yet the links are not working...

The code...

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Portfolio Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js">      
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">

            <div class="navbar-brand">Photo Gallery</div>

        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Nature Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Science Gallery</a></li>

        </ul>


    </div>

</nav>

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

            <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="slider">

                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                </ol>

                <div class="carousel-inner">

                    <div class="item active"><img src="img/slide01.png"></div>
                    <div class="item"><img src="img/slide02.png"></div>
                    <div class="item"><img src="img/slide01.png"></div>
                    <div class="item"><img src="img/slide02.png"></div>

                </div>

                <a href="#slider" data-slide="prev" class="left carousel-control">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                </a>

                <a href="#slider" data-slide="next" class="right carousel-control">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                </a>

            </div>


        </div>

    </div>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Another issue is, I am using images of 750px*300px and in desktop view there is grey shade area on the right of the image. While in the mobile or responsive view that grey shade area isnt visible. Can someone please suggest how to rectify the issue?

Please help people, I am new to web-designing and new to stackoverflow too :)

Comment: Where is the markup for the Carousel?

Answer (score 0):

Your links wont work because you need to load jquery.js before bootstrap.js so just flip these around in your head section. Also you need to load jquery and not jquery ui so it should look something like the following

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Then your images need to have some css to get them to fill the carousel

```
#slider .item {
  height: 250px;
}
#slider .item img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Here is a fiddle for you to see this working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/f4ewvuhy/)

The only thing about this is images can become skewed in responsive design and images have different sizes so you may want to create a background image for each of the carousel items.  Like so

```
#slider .item {
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}
#slider .first-item{
  background: url('http://placehold.it/350x150');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
#slider .second-item{
  background: url('http://placehold.it/350x150');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
#slider .third-item{
  background: url('http://placehold.it/350x150');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
#slider .fourth-item{
  background: url('http://placehold.it/350x150');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

and your html for the carousel inner will look like this:

```
            <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="item active first-item"></div>
                <div class="item second-item"></div>
                <div class="item third-item"></div>
                <div class="item fourth-item"></div>

            </div>
```

Here is a fiddle of that working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/wgdxqtao/)

Comment: I have edited my answer as I found that you have loaded jquery ui instead of the actual jquery library.  Also welcome to stackoverflow.  If you need any more assistance feel free to comment here and I will be more than happy to help

Comment: But one part of the issue is still there, my slider links are not working on the localhost, yet the same code works on JSFiddle!

Comment: Ok make sure that you are loading jquery and not jquery ui like I said in the comment before.  Then make sure that you are loading jquery first and then bootstrap.  Bootstrap works off of jquery so you need to have the link to jquery.js above bootstrap.js.  Also use the link that I provided in my edit to the answer as I saw that you had a link to jquery ui which is not actually the jquery library you need to load.  I have them in the right order above after my edit so just copy and paste them over yours like I have them in my answer.

Comment: PERFECT!!! Thanks for helping me out here, I missed your comment in the answer about the UI and that was the issue!

Comment: THANKS A LOT! again!

Comment: No problem if you got everything working don't forget to check it as the right answer so people visit the forum can see which answers were correct.  Also I forgot to close the script tag in my answer I will edit that as well.  Happy Coding :)